# How to Poll for a value change/key creation using promise in firebase

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have a client side code (apps script html) where there is a button for buy now.

The user clicks the buy button and completes the payment from a payment site. The payment site sends an ipn notification and the ipn script create a key by name "email" and sets the value as "purchased"

Meanwhile, the buy now button code has to poll the firebase database continuously whether the key and a value is created/modified/renewed in the firebase database. when created it must activate and show the message thank you for buying, other wise keep quiet checking until the dialog is closed.

Polling consumes time, ie repeatedly checking the value whether created?

I have no idea what the promises are. But is there a way by using promise I can check the key and value after clicking the buy now button?

Can someone help me to write the code. Whether this kind of an approach is feasible in firebase?

Comment: You should use [Firebase read/write docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) - the "Listen for value events" section. Check out the example with `starCountRef.on('value',...`

Comment: "Meanwhile, the buy now button code has to poll the firebase database continuously"  This is an anti-pattern in code that reads the Firebase Database. With Firebase you attach a listener once, and it will then immediately call your code when the value changes. If you have trouble getting this to work from the docs that @BlunderingPhilosopher linked, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).